# How to use actors while retaining the ability to do structured concurrency in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a class which uses an `actor` to ensure thread safety of shared mutable state. I made a small wrapper around this `actor` to make it easy to use:

```
interface Ref<T : Any> {

    fun get(): T

    fun transform(transformer: (T) -> T): Job

}
```

Here `get` uses `runBlocking` to block until it fetches the actual value of `T`:

```
override fun get(): T = runBlocking {
    val deferred = CompletableDeferred<T>()
    launch {
        actor.send(RefOperation.Get(deferred))
    }
    deferred.await()
}
```

and `transform` does something similar without `runBlocking` and just returns a `Job`:

```
override fun transform(transformer: (T) -> T): Job {
    val job = Job()
    launch {
        actor.send(RefOperation.Transform(transformer, job))
    }
    return job
}
```

This is fine until a `transform` call leads to another one:

```
ref.transform {

  ...
  ref.transform {

  }
}
```

Here I have 2 `Job`s but there is no way to combine them to a single `Job` on which I can call `join()` if I want to wait for their completion.

The solution for this would be structured concurrency but then I don't know how to create my `actor` anymore since it is defined as an extension on `CoroutineScope`.

How can I keep using an `actor` while retaining the ability to use structured concurrency?

**Note that** I've created `Ref` because my project is multiplatform and for targets other than the JVM I use alternative implementations.

Answer (score 5):

`actor` processes items in the same order as they were added, and does it sequentially in a single coroutine. It means that inner `transform` will be processed AFTER completion of outer `transform`, and you can't change it while you are using `actor` (in `actor` we can't launch more coroutines, because we confine our state to a single thread, otherwise recurrent processing order would be possible). Trying to join the job of inner `transform` in body of outer `transform` (if we mark `transform` as suspended function) will just cause deadlock.

Are you OK with such behaviour? If not, don't use either actors or nested transforms. If yes, please provide some use cases where creating a nested `transform` that will be processed after outer `transform` makes any sense.

As for joining all the jobs, I've got some code. In `main` we have outer transform that creates an inner transform. Outer one returns 2, inner one returns 8, but inner one starts after completion of outer one, so the result is 8. But as you wanted, `transformJob.join()` in `main` waits for inner job too.

```java
private sealed class RefOperation<T>
private class Get<T : Any>(val deferred: CompletableDeferred<T>) : RefOperation<T>()
private class Transform<T : Any>(val transformer: TransformStub<T>.(T) -> T, val stub: TransformStub<T>, val job: CompletableJob) : RefOperation<T>()

interface Ref<T : Any> {

    fun get(): T

    fun transform(transformer: TransformStub<T>.(T) -> T): Job

}

interface TransformStub<T : Any> {
    fun transform(transformer: TransformStub<T>.(T) -> T): Job
}

private class TransformStubImpl<T : Any>(
        val actor: SendChannel<RefOperation<T>>,
        val scope: CoroutineScope
) : TransformStub<T> {

    override fun transform(transformer: TransformStub<T>.(T) -> T): Job {
        return scope.launch {
            val childJob: CompletableJob = Job()
            val childStub = TransformStubImpl(actor, this)
            actor.send(Transform(transformer, childStub, childJob))
            childJob.join()
        }
    }

}

class RefImpl<T : Any>(initialValue: T) : Ref<T> {

    private val actorJob = Job()
    private val actorScope = CoroutineScope(actorJob)
    private val actor = actorScope.actor<RefOperation<T>> {
        var value: T = initialValue
        for (msg in channel) {
            when (msg) {
                is Get -> {
                    println("Get! $value")
                    msg.deferred.complete(value)
                }
                is Transform -> {
                    with(msg) {
                        val newValue = stub.transformer(value)
                        println("Transform! $value -> $newValue")
                        value = newValue
                        job.complete()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun get(): T = runBlocking {
        val deferred = CompletableDeferred<T>()
        actor.send(Get(deferred))
        deferred.await()
    }

    override fun transform(transformer: TransformStub<T>.(T) -> T): Job {
        val stub = TransformStubImpl(actor, GlobalScope)
        return stub.transform(transformer)
    }

}

fun main() = runBlocking<Unit> {
    val ref: Ref<Int> = RefImpl(0)
    val transformJob = ref.transform {
        transform { 8 }
        2
    }
    transformJob.join()
    ref.get()
}
```